# Angular 2 with PHP login sessions or JWT

Tags: php, angular, session, jwt

I am new to angular 2.
I am working on a project based on Angular 2 and PHP as the backend server where I get JSON data from server.
My problem now is how to create a login system. In some places online, I saw that it is not allowed anymore to work with PHP sessions if we are working with angular2.
My questions are:

1. Why we cannot work with sessions anymore;
2. What is JWT, and is there any example to work with alongside MySQL ?
3. If a user with an ID of 638 logged in, how this token is saved and retrieved on each component of page of my web app, so the user can only see his proper data.

It is confusing and I know that this question does not contain any codes. But still needs your help.

Comment: That's a fairly broad question. If I were you I would read up about JWT first (https://jwt.io/introduction/). You need to learn how to generate a token in your language of choice, e.g. PHP. Note that this part doesn't have anything to do with Angular (or MySQL for that matter). Then, Angular's responsibility is "only" to include the token when sending requests to the backend. How the token should be passed really depends on YOUR specific backend: it could be in a URL parameter, or in the HTTP headers... Angular has specific syntaxes for both but first you need to learn how YOUR backend works.

Comment: so each time I request data from server, the token is generated again ? Or it is set only once on the login ? Still confused.

Comment: No. If you plan on using JWT for authentication, your backend generates and returns a new token when the user successfully logs in using their credentials. This token must be persisted by the client (Angular) somehow. You can use the browser's localStorage or simply store the token in memory (in a variable inside your Angular app). Then, you include the token in all subsequent requests that your app makes.

Comment: Again, this is explained on the jwt.io website and in numerous tutorials. Please read the doc first.

Comment: Okay sir. I will start with right now